# npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted,

Tags: npm, vagrant, npm-install, homestead

I am trying to run npm install and keep getting permission errors regardless if I run it as an admin. My environment specifications are the following.

```
Windows 7
Virtual Box 5.1
Vagrant 2.0.1
Homestead Box
NPM 5.5.1
NODE 8.9.1
```

I have already searched through different support sites and tried suggested fixes but I always get a new issue related to permission with error:

```
npm ERR! ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rmdir
```

or

```
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted,
```

I used the command `npm install --no-bin-links' and it still do not work.

```js
sudo npm install --no-bin-links
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/Code/project/node_modules/sum-up
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename '/home/vagrant/Code/project/node_modules/sum-up' -> '/home/vagrant/Code/project/node_modules/.sum-up.DELETE'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename '/home/vagrant/Code/project/node_modules/sum-up' -> '/home/vagrant/Code/project/node_modules/.sum-up.DELETE'
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename '/home/vagrant/Code/project/node_modules/sum-up' -> '/home/vagrant/Code/project/node_modules/.sum-up.DELETE'
npm ERR!      errno: -1,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!      path: '/home/vagrant/Code/project/node_modules/sum-up',
npm ERR!      dest: '/home/vagrant/Code/project/node_modules/.sum-up.DELETE' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename \'/home/vagrant/Code/project/node_modules/sum-up\' -> \'/home/vagrant/Code/project/node_modules/.sum-up.DELETE\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/vagrant/Code/project/node_modules/sum-up',
npm ERR!   dest: '/home/vagrant/Code/project/node_modules/.sum-up.DELETE' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2018-01-23T19_51_11_713Z-debug.log
```

Comment: it seems that npm doesn't have the permission to write on this folder.
Look at the doc here : https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: Thank Ragnar, I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: For me it's 99% sure it's a permission issue.

Try also : `npm cache clean --force` then `npm install -g npm@latest --force` then `npm cache clean --force`

Other solution, install `yarn` and try with it.

Answer (score 4):

The underlying problem is related to how Windows file locking is handled by Virtualbox sharing. It happens whether using standard shared folders (vboxsf) or nfs. If a file is opened or read (locked) by another process while `npm` is trying to change it the whole install process fails.

How to fix:

1. Run `vagrant up` (and other commands) from an administrator terminal. This ensures symlinks work correctly. There are other ways to enable symlinks - if you use one of them be sure to test them out using `ln -s a b` within the shared folder.
2. Ensure that no other process opens any of the files in the shared folder by either disabling the process or excluding the vagrant folder. This includes, but is not limited to:

   1. Windows Defender or other anti virus software
   2. Windows search index or other indexing software
   3. Dropbox or other file synchronisation software.

If you are still having issues with point 2 above, you can use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), filtered to your vagrant directory, to detect access by any process other than Virtualbox (VBoxHeadless.exe).

With the above in place I am able to successfully run `npm install` without issue.

Answer (score 4):

When I got a similar error, I closed the Visual Studio code editor and ran npm install. It solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I simply had to close my Visual Studio Code IDE which had opened the package.json file, tried npm install after this and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, not sure exactly how, but seems like an external Windows service was locking part of npm files. So I had to mount an external folder in my vagrant (that is out of my project) and that is not directly visible from Windows, and use this folder as npm node_modules folder:

```
sudo mkdir /node_modules && sudo chmod 777 /node_modules
sudo mount --bind /node_modules /vagrant/real_path_to_your_app/node_modules
```

Also add this line in your /etc/fstab:

```
/node_modules   /vagrant/real_path_to_your_app/node_modules   none   bind    0    0
```

Then from within /vagrant/real_path_to_your_app you can execute:

```
/vagrant/real_path_to_your_app$ sudo npm install --save your_module
```

It worked for me - actually using mounted directory /node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on Eclipse IDE. Solution is to restart it and then run `npm install`. After that all was ok.